# create plot instead of label on pine script

Tags: pine-script

this is the default script on trading view for pivot points

```
//@version=4
study("Pivot Points High Low", shorttitle="Pivots HL", overlay=true)
lenH = input(title="Length High", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false
    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false
    if isFound
        label.new(bar_index[len], p, tostring(p), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color)
fun(high, lenH, true, label.style_labeldown, yloc.abovebar, color.lime)
fun(low, lenL, false, label.style_labelup, yloc.belowbar, color.red)
```

how I can change the labels to plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Difficulties with translation.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Pivot Points High Low)", shorttitle="Pivots HL", overlay=true)
lenH = input(title="Length High", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
//fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color) =>
fun(src, len, isHigh) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false
    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false
    if isFound
//        label.new(bar_index[len], p, tostring(p), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color)
        p

plotH = fun(high, lenH, true) //, label.style_label_down, yloc.abovebar, color.lime)
plotL = fun(low, lenL, false) //, label.style_label_up, yloc.belowbar, color.red)

plot(plotH, color=color.lime, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, offset=-lenH)
plot(plotL, color=color.red,  linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, offset=-lenL)
```

Comment: how I can make the plot style is continuous circles ?

Comment: Add parameter `join=true` to function `plot`.

Comment: could you help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798192/requests-too-many-securities-at-pinescript