# Requests too many securities at PineScript

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make this script by adding all Binance pairs which are over 250 pairs but I am getting this message: "Script requests too many securities: 48. The limit is 40"

is there any idea to add all Binance pairs? I found this solution but I didn't know how to use it on my code this the solution link: https://kodify.net/tradingview/errors/request-too-many-securities/
and here is my sample code :

```
//@version=4
study("Custom Screener", overlay = false)
customFunc() => close > open

s1  = security('BTCUSD',  '1', customFunc())

scr_label = 'Screener: \n##########\n'

scr_label := s1  ? scr_label + 'BTCUSD\n'  : scr_label

lab_l = label.new(
      bar_index, 0, scr_label, 
      color=color.gray, 
      textcolor=color.black, 
      style =  label.style_labeldown,
      yloc = yloc.price)

label.delete(lab_l[1])

plot(0, transp = 100)
```

Comment: As the error stay - it's a platform's limitation, you can't call more than 40 security functions simultaneously.

Comment: If you only need to display labels, then there is an option to split the output into several studies.

Comment: yes I want only to display the labels

Answer (score 1):

!This solution does not help in the exact situation asked in this ticket. But the workaround might help in other situations where multiple security calls are done on the same symbol with the same timeframe. All of those can be combined to one call like this:

```
 lrc = ta.linreg(close, 20, 0)
 symbolResultText = request.security(symbol, "D", str.format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", open, close, lrc[0], lrc[1], lrc[2]), barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
 symbolResultArray = str.split(symbolResultText, ";")

 symbolOpen = array.get(symbolResultArray, 0)
 symbolClose = array.get(symbolResultArray, 1)
 symbolLrc0 = str.tonumber(array.get(symbolResultArray, 2))
 symbolLrc1 = str.tonumber(array.get(symbolResultArray, 3))
 symbolLrc2 = str.tonumber(array.get(symbolResultArray, 4))
```

Here we are getting open, close and 3 indicator values in one call.